# in ubuntu docker-container sed command doesn't replace /permitrootlogin prohibit-password/permitrootlogin yes/

Tags: docker, sed, dockerfile, devops, openssh

i am learing docker and try to write a dockerfile for a image with openssh-server to give access to root user via password throuh ssh the docker file i wrote is below

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget openssh-server -y
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin Prohibit-RootLogin/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo 'root:root123' | chpasswd
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
EXPOSE 22
```

while creating image there is no error was shown after created a container using this image I checked the sshd_config file in the container but the PermitRootLogin does not change to yes it is still in prohibit-password and tried to login with serverip&portnumber in putty i gave login as root and root123 as password but access was denied can anyone explain why it didn't change? and how can i modify sshd_config file?

i tried build the image with --no-cache if the system ignorin the sed command because of cache and i tried different version of ubumtu as base os  if that is the  problem i tried to wirting anew docker file without sed command to replace the permitrootlogin option but with echo command and mv command but that also didn't work the second docker file i wrote is the following

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER ananth
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget openssh-server -y
RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" > /etc/ssh/sshd_config_new
RUN mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config_new /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
EXPOSE 22
```

Comment: It's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that you want to modify.  Not `ssh_config`.

Comment: sorry i typed it wrong here but i tried sshd_config in my server it doesn't  working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion based on a slight variation of your initial Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget openssh-server -y
RUN echo 'PermitRootLogin yes' > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/root.conf
RUN echo 'root:root123' | chpasswd
EXPOSE 22/tcp
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

The idea is to drop a (single directive) configuration file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` instead of modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` through `sed`.

Also, keep in mind that the `EXPOSE` statement in not enough to set up your networking requirements. As the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) says:

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on
> the specified network ports at runtime. You can specify whether the
> port listens on TCP or UDP, and the default is TCP if the protocol is
> not specified.
>
> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
> functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
> image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
> intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
> the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
> more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
> to high-order ports.

So the sequence of instructions to instantiate your docker container would be something like:

```
cd somepath/to/your/dockerfile
docker image build .
docker container create -p LOCALPORT:22 IMAGE_ID
docker container start CONTAINER_ID
```

Then you should be able to `ssh root@localhost -p LOCALPORT`.

Of course, do not use 22 as LOCALPORT, you'd end up connecting to the host OS `sshd` process.

Hope that helps!